# scanning a string with whitespaces

Tags: c, string

I am facing problem in printing a string with whitespaces. What is wrong with the following code and how can i avoid it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str[50]; 
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str);
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

input: 2
    i am ed
    i am from us
    the output which gets printed are some weird characters
    can somebody help me out in this!

Comment: If you want to read whole lines, then I really suggest you use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead of `scanf`.

Comment: Changing the input format string to `"%49[^\n]%*c"` will fix some (but not all) of your problems. As suggested above, use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 2):

> What is wrong with the following code

The `scanf("%d",&t)` consumes only the `2` from the input, but not the `\n` following it, hence all the `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str)` encounter that `\n` and return immediately, consuming no input and reading nothing into `str`, leaving it with undefined content.

> how can i avoid it?

If you don't mind to skip leading space, you could use `scanf(" %[^\n]", str)`.

Answer (score -1):

`%[^\n]` stops reading once it meets the newline character even if no char is read. So the `str` array is left uninitialized after `scanf`. That's why `printf` prints weird characters.

Just change `"%[^\n]%*c"` to `"%*c%[^\n]"` and you get it.